# Select from list elements greater than next element

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Given

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0}
```

I want to get all the elements which are greater than the right neighbor. The result would be

```
{3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}
```

I can do it by

```
t2 = Partition[t1, 2, 1]
Select[t2, #[[1]] > #[[2]] &][[All, 1]]
```

But I am looking for a solution like

```
Select[t1, #1 > #2 &]
```

which does not work

Comment: `Most[Last /@ Split[t1, Less]]`?

Answer (score 13):

#### 1.

```
Pick[Most @ t1, UnitStep @ Differences @ t1, 0]
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}
> ```

#### 2.

```
t1[[Random`Private`PositionsOf[UnitStep @ Differences @ t1, 0]]]
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}
> ```

Comment: Pick[Most @ t1, Sign @ Differences @ t1, -1]

Answer (score 12):

We `MapApply` `Greater` on partitions of the list with offset, then use `Pick` to select all the valid elements.

```
list = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0};

Pick[Most@list, Greater @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1], True]

(* Out: {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5} *)
```

##### Performance

Here is the performance of this answer compare to others on a list of 1,000 random integers in Mathematica 13.3:

| Answer | RepeatedTiming | MaxMemoryUsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kglr's `Pick` - 1 | **0.000014** | 30880 |
| kglr's `Pick` - 2 | 0.000015 | **22632** |
| Ben's `Pick` | 0.00041 | 184984 |
| Syed `Split` | 0.00044 | 93920 |
| ydd's `Ordering` | 0.00082 | 124112 |
| Daniel Huber's `MapIndexed` | 0.002 | 281848 |
| lericr's `SequenceCases` | 1.9 | 4522768 |

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this?

```
SequenceCases[t1, {a_, _}?(Apply[Greater]) :> a, Overlaps -> True]
```

Comment: A bit neater perhaps: ```SequenceCases[list, ({a_, b_} /; (a > b)) :> a, Overlaps -> True]```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using "MapIndexed". This delivers not only the list element, but as second argument also its position. Increasing this by one, you can reach the next element. Look it up in the help.

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0};
MapIndexed[If[#1 > t1[[#2[[1]] + 1]], #1, Nothing[]] &, Most@t1]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0};
```

**Using `FoldPairList`:**

```
FoldPairList[If[#1 > #2, {#1, #2}, {, #2}] &, t1] /. Null -> Nothing
```

**Using `Split`:**

```
Split[t1, #1 > #2 &] // Map[Most] // Flatten
```

or alternatively:

```
Split[t1, Greater] // Map[Most] // Flatten
```

---

Original answer (didn't read the post all the way; it was already there)

```
First /@ Select[Partition[t1, 2, 1], First@# > Last@# &]
```

or using the operator form:

```
Map[First][Select[First@# > Last@# &][Partition[t1, 2, 1]]]
```

---

Result

> {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the [`DeleteAdjacentDuplicates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteAdjacentDuplicates.html) can be abused:

```
list={3,2,8,6,1,9,4,1,5,0};
Most[Reverse@DeleteAdjacentDuplicates[Reverse@list, Greater]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Could take the differences in the ordering of the ordering and select where it's less than 0

```
t1[[Position[Differences@Ordering@Ordering[t1], n_ /; n < 0] // 
   Flatten]]
```

Basically the same thing but using `RotateLeft`:

```
t1[[Position[Most[t1 - RotateLeft[t1]], n_ /; n > 0]//Flatten]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

```
fun[u_] := 
 Reap[Sow @@@ 
    Thread[{u, 
      ArrayPad[Sign@*Differences@u, {0, 1}, "x"]}], -1, #2 &][[2, 1]]
```

Testing:

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0}
fun[t1]
```

yields: {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}

```
# -> fun[#] & /@ RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[{a_, b_} /; a > b :> a] @ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

{3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[Partition[t1, 2, 1], #[[1]] > #[[2]] &, #[[All, 1]] &], True]

(*{3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Single pass with a loop, no copy:

```
l = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0} ;
Reap[
   Do[
    With[
     {a = l[[i]], b = l[[i + 1]] },
     If[a > b, Sow[a]]
     ],
    {i, 1, Length[l] - 1}
    ]
   ] // Last // First
```

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

```
t1[[Lookup[-1]@PositionIndex@Sign@Differences@t1]]

(* {3, 8, 6, 9, 4, 5} *)
```

Or, a slight variant with `UnitStep` instead of `Sign`:

```
t1[[Lookup[0]@PositionIndex@UnitStep@Differences@t1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0};

k={t1[[#]],(t1[[#]]-t1[[#+1]])}&/@Range[Length[t1]-1];

First/@Select[k,#[[2]]≥0&]
```

Resultat

```
{3,8,6,9,4,5}
```

Autre code:

```
t1 = {3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 0};

k=t1-Insert[TakeList[t1,{1,All}][[2]],0,-1];

Select[Sign[k]*t1,#>0&]
```

Resultat

```
{3,8,6,9,4,5}
```

This code is more speed and simple:

```
Select[-Sign[Insert[Differences[t1],-1,-1]]*t1,#>0&]
```